How do I pass pointer to a function?
How do I pass p[0] to a function and print its content?
#include "stdio.h"
    
void setupMidiOctave(int *p[]) {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int b[] = {4, 5, 6};

    p[0]    = &a[0];
    p[1]    = &b[0];
}

void prt(int *a) {
    printf("%d\n", a[1]);
}

int main(void) {
    int *p[2];
    setupMidiOctave(p);
    printf("%d\n", p[0][0]);
    prt(p[0]); // <--------- not printing out
    return 0;
}


You can't use pointers to local variables after the function has returned. &a[0] becomes invalid after setupMidiOctave() returns.

Either make a and b static or global variables, or allocate memory dynamically.

Why is p an array of pointers instead of just an array of integers?

Within setupMidiOctave you are trying to return pointers into two arrays declared with automatic storage duration. Once the function call is completed, those pointers no longer point to valid memory. Attempting to use them invokes undefined behavior.
To overcome this in your situation, a and b need to be allocated dynamically so that they outlive the function call.
void setupMidiOctave(int *p[]) {
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * 3);
    int *b = malloc(sizeof(*b) * 3);

    a[0] = 1; a[1] = 2; a[2] = 3;
    b[0] = 4; b[1] = 5; b[2] = 6;

    p[0] = a;
    p[1] = b;
}

But now don't forget to free this dynamically allocated memory when you're done with it.
You should also get into the habit of checking that malloc succeeded. You may want your function to return a value to indicate this. You'll want to clean up if the first malloc succeeds but the second fails, to avoid memory leaks. It also makes using a and b make more sense as we now have the option to not overwrite p if the dynamic allocation fails.
int setupMidiOctave(int *p[]) {
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * 3);
    if (!a) {
        return 0;
    }

    int *b = malloc(sizeof(*b) * 3);
    if (!b) {
        free(a);
        return 0;
    }

    a[0] = 1; a[1] = 2; a[2] = 3;
    b[0] = 4; b[1] = 5; b[2] = 6;

    p[0] = a;
    p[1] = b;

    return 1;
}


I'm not down-voting the answer this time, but please don't answer super-obvious duplicates that have been asked a million times before. Instead close as duplicate. A list of targets can be found in the C tag wiki below FAQ.
